# rapidshare like site loading

Tags: jquery

How can i make pages load like **rapidshare** without reloading window?

for example:

https://rapidshare.com/#!home

if you browse through pages, browser window is not reloading, it just change last parameter of url like #!myrs_overview, #!buyrapids, #!help etc

when i see it in firebug it is giving that parameter name, i.e from above (home,buyrapids)
http://screensnapr.com/v/wPJtCY.png

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#!` is called a hashbang, and it's the [standard for allowing Google to crawl ajax pages](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/). They're simply using AJAX to repopulate the page information and then updating the hash url:

Take the following example navigation link:

```
<a href="contact.php" title="Contact Us" id="contact-us">Contact</a>
```

If we don't want the page to redirect to `contact.php` but we want to load the content, we could do this instead:

```
<a href="#!contact" class="nav-link" rel="contact.php" title="Contact Us" id="contact-us">Contact</a>
```

Then with JQuery:

```
$('.nav-link').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: $this.attr('rel'),
        success: function(data){
            $('body').fadeOut().html(data).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

If someone enters your site with the hashbang in the url, we simply detect it and load the appropriate page; something like this would work:

```
$(function(){
    if(window.location.hash){
        if(window.location.hash.indexOf('#!') === 0){
            $.ajax({
                url: window.location.hash.replace('#!','') + '.php',
                success: function(data){
                    $('body').fadeOut().html(data).fadeIn();
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , i tried as per your suggestion but its not working ,can you please tell me what i am doing wrong here? http://paste2.org/p/1677031

Comment: Yea `$(this)` was out of scope. It's too early :) See updated code.

Comment: Thanks again ok that function works but not the contact href tag, if i goto url it load successfully index.php#!contact but if i click on href it just change url from index.php to index.php#!contact but no change on page.

Comment: Well, my example assumes a few things if you're using it as-is. It assumes your anchor has a class called `nav-link`, it assumes you assigned `rel="contact.php"`, it assumes you have a php page in the same directory called `contact.php`, and of course it assumes you are using a current version of JQuery. What have you tried as far as debugging goes? Are any errors showing up in your console? Is the ajax call successful
?

Comment: Edit: sorry i forgot to add $(document).ready(function() { around code it works alright now , thank you for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is AJAX. The "last parameter" is not a GET-Parameter but an anchor, which is read by JavaScript.

Some tips on starting with this technique can be found on [ajaxprojects.com](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=10)

Comment: It's most of the times ajax, but not necessarily ajax. All content might have been loaded on a single page, and different parts are shown. The term is anchor/hash, which is being set on `location.hash` and retried from there.